Kubernetes POD error - java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
Facing this below error when consuming Rest API present in another POD in Kubernetes cluster using ingress URL through Feign client.
Error-  java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
Even after settingup jdk proxy and tunneling below properties same error but its intermittent issue.
Properties-
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes=""
Strange thing is-
this error is intermittent & not static error after adding above two properties in jdk System properties.

Do you have any Namespace separation secured by any active NetworkPolicy?

Yeah there’s namespace for both PODs uniquely

Any NetworkPolicy running?

Yes, only ingress (to incoming requests) & there isn't egress configured (to outgoing requests)

Wait… No egress configured? Does the Pod not need to call anything outside its Namespace? Is there really just a data flow from outside the Namespace inside?
